# Add mapping ip and host into /etc/hosts with docker

Tags: docker, shell-script, bash

I am using docker to scale my service.
I know there's a command called `--add--host` for adding host into /etc/host

However, I have a bunch of hosts need to be added. It's just too long to launch a docker in this way

```
docker run -it \
  --add-host=testing1.example.com:10.0.0.1 \
  --add-host=testing2.example.com:10.0.0.2 \
  --add-host=testing3.example.com:10.0.0.3 \
  ...
```

Therefore, I was thinking to create a function to read a mapping file and solve the problem.

The file format is like the following

**host-list**

```
14.64.65.3 A
11.64.65.18 B
12.64.65.23 C
13.10.200.63 D
13.10.5.77 E
14.10.5.72 F
15.10.5.81 G
...
```

I am new on shell script and have no idea to start with.

Comment: get your shell to read one line at a time from your host-list file then have shell echo the needed syntax you show ... this is a couple lines of bash

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use docker compose and the docker compose "extra_hosts" tag, as described on the docker compose specification at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/.

> extra_hosts
>
> Add hostname mappings. Use the same values as the docker client --add-host parameter.
>
> extra_hosts:
>
> - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
> - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
>
> An entry with the ip address and hostname is created in /etc/hosts 
>   for this service, e.g:
>
> 162.242.195.82  somehost
>
> 50.31.209.229   otherhostinside containers

So, this will mean, that you need to use docker compose in addition to docker.